# How to increase memory for embedded jvm for a deployed javafx application?

Tags: deployment, javafx, jvm, ram

I am using a .fxbuild-script to build a JavaFX Application. I used Packaging-Format all to include its own runtime. Now I am wondering, how I can define any runtime parameters?

Since we noticed, that we had far more OutOfMemory Issuses within the deployed version than with the local development version, we were monitioring it with Visual VM and noticed, that the embedded JVM (by default?) is only configured to use 256MB of RAM. How can I increase the Maximum available RAM for the included JVM?

The Application is launched by an .exe file after beeing installed on the system.

**Update**:
The Answer of Roland is correct. I just made the mistake, that I added the `<fx:platform>`-Tag at the Bottom of the Ant script and not within the appropriate `<fx:deploy>`-Tag which results in that the `<fx:platform>`-Tag will be ignored and the JVM is configured to use 256 MB max RAM on 32-Bit and 1/4th of available RAM on 64-Bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the [Packaging Basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/packaging.htm), especially chapter "5.8.2 Customizing JVM Setup".

Excerpt of what you need:

```
<fx:platform javafx="2.1+">
    <fx:jvmarg value="-Xmx400m"/>
    ...
</fx:platform>
```

Comment: thank you, already tried this chapter, but unfortunatly adding this to the generated build script didn´t increase the available memory (at least Visual VM and Debug Log say so). Moreover I wasn´t sure, if I really should manually add changes to the generated build script, since its probably desired to let it getting generated several times afterwards. Is this really the intended use to do this? And do I need to reference the fx:platform target somewhere, so it works?